# Your configuration files are not serializable

Tags: laravel-5, config

I ran

```
php artisan config:cache
```

on my terminal and i got a LogicException

```
LogicException  : Your configuration files are not serializable.

at C:\xampp\htdocs\{PROJECT}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ConfigCacheCommand.php:68

 64|             require $configPath;
 65|         } catch (Throwable $e) {
 66|             $this->files->delete($configPath);
 67|
 68|             throw new LogicException('Your configuration files are not serializable.', 0, $e);
 69|         }
 70|
 71|         $this->info('Configuration cached successfully!');
 72|     }

 Exception trace:

1   Error::("Call to undefined method Closure::__set_state()")
  C:\xampp\htdocs\{PROJECT}\bootstrap\cache\config.php:241

2   require()
  C:\xampp\htdocs\{PROJECT}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ConfigCacheCommand.php:64

Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

I've never encountered this error before when running this command. Please any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This happened to me when I was running PHP 7.2 upgrading to 7.4 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Closure serialization is not allowed in Laravel and PHP at large. Look through your configuration files for any file where you used Closures and rewrite that piece of code using traditional functions.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the last published config file and it worked.

Comment: But this configuration file I removed is required by a package (CKFinder). How do I rewrite the file using traditional functions.

Answer (score 27):

To find out where exactly the issue is, you can temporarily remove `$this->files->delete($configPath);` from `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ConfigCacheCommand.php`. By doing so `bootstrap/cache/config.php` does not get automatically deleted and you can look up the mentioned line (here 241) in the config.php file.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to a similar error.

I discovered that my error related to a closure in the /config/sluggable.php file (of a package for managing slugs that I had installed.

My code was as follows:

```
return [
    reserved => function(Model $model){
        return HelperController::reservedSlugs();
    }
];
```

I did the following to test if this closure was the cause of the issue:

```
return [
   reserved => array()
]
```

Then I ran `php artisan optimize`. There was no longer an issue - I had found the closure that was causing the problem.

So, instead of the original closure, I did the following to get the same result:

$reservedSlugs = HelperController::reservedSlugs();

```
return [
    'reserved' => $reservedSlugs
];
```

Comment: Did you include the class inside the config file? Otherwise, can you give a hand with [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72061652/1883256)?

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same issue.
I only add **toarray()** function to **Setting::first()** then its worked.
config only get array values not array of objects.

```
config([
        'global' =>  Settings::first()->toarray(),
    ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to remove the 'vendor' folder
then:

1. composer install
2. composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same issue when I run

> php artisan config:cache

it shows me this error

```
  Your configuration files are not serializable.
  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ConfigCacheCommand.php:71
  67|             require $configPath;
  68|         } catch (Throwable $e) {
  69|             $this->files->delete($configPath);
  70|
  > 71|             throw new LogicException('Your configuration files are not serializable.', 0, $e);
  72|         }
  73|
  74|         $this->info('Configuration cached successfully!');
  75|     }
  1   bootstrap\cache\config.php:671
  Error::("Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Rules\In::__set_state()")
  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ConfigCacheCommand.php:67
  require()
```

When I debug all Configuration in `Project/config` directory I found a config file `config/installer.php` created by package `https://github.com/rashidlaasri/LaravelInstaller` that uses `Rule::in(['true', 'false'])` so I change this piece of code with `'in:true,false'` now work like a charm hope this will help someone

Answer (score 2):

Instead of defining as object

```
'callback' => new App\Http\Controllers\PaymentController()
```

define as class

```
'callback' => App\Http\Controllers\PaymentController::class
```

in any config file

Answer (score 1):

My config file app.php has injection from constructor. In this constructor has requests from eloquent. This requests give errors with serialization. I use ->get()->toArray() for correction. Also I change other objects to array: $array->field to $array['field']. No errors.