# "Your configuration files are not serializable" error message after adding GELF logger in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, gelf

After adding GELF logging according to this how to https://medium.com/@vaidaslungis/setup-graylog-in-laravel-5-6-logging-d2276bcb9cfa
the `php artisan config:cache` command isn't working anymore.

```
The error message is:


In ConfigCacheCommand.php line 68:

  Your configuration files are not serializable.  


In config.php line 382:

  Call to undefined method Gelf\Publisher::__set_state()
```

Is it still possible to cache the config? If so, what needs to be changed?

Comment: Have you tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065513/your-configuration-files-are-not-serializable)

Comment: What do you mean by try? It says that Closures aren't working for config caching. From the example, I'm not sure where a Closure is used. Can you spot one?

Answer (score 0):

In case an error occurs while logging, the exception is stored in a class variable of the IgnoreErrorTransportWrapper ($lastError). The exception is not serializable, therefore the serialization of the logger fails.