# use persian characters as slug in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 8 and use `cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable` to make slug for products

so it works well when I use english title but whenever I use Persian for example "تست" slug save as a english translate like this "tst" I change method of sluggable

after that method in `config/sluggable` change

```
'method' => function($string, $separator = '-')
{
    $_transliteration = array(
        '/ä|æ|ǽ/' => 'ae',
        '/ö|œ/' => 'oe',
        '/ü/' => 'ue',
        '/Ä/' => 'Ae',
        '/Ü/' => 'Ue',
        '/Ö/' => 'Oe',
        '/À|Á|Â|Ã|Å|Ǻ|Ā|Ă|Ą|Ǎ/' => 'A',
        '/à|á|â|ã|å|ǻ|ā|ă|ą|ǎ|ª/' => 'a',
        '/Ç|Ć|Ĉ|Ċ|Č/' => 'C',
        '/ç|ć|ĉ|ċ|č/' => 'c',
        '/Ð|Ď|Đ/' => 'D',
        '/ð|ď|đ/' => 'd',
        '/È|É|Ê|Ë|Ē|Ĕ|Ė|Ę|Ě/' => 'E',
        '/è|é|ê|ë|ē|ĕ|ė|ę|ě/' => 'e',
        '/Ĝ|Ğ|Ġ|Ģ/' => 'G',
        '/ĝ|ğ|ġ|ģ/' => 'g',
        '/Ĥ|Ħ/' => 'H',
        '/ĥ|ħ/' => 'h',
        '/Ì|Í|Î|Ï|Ĩ|Ī|Ĭ|Ǐ|Į|İ/' => 'I',
        '/ì|í|î|ï|ĩ|ī|ĭ|ǐ|į|ı/' => 'i',
        '/Ĵ/' => 'J',
        '/ĵ/' => 'j',
        '/Ķ/' => 'K',
        '/ķ/' => 'k',
        '/Ĺ|Ļ|Ľ|Ŀ|Ł/' => 'L',
        '/ĺ|ļ|ľ|ŀ|ł/' => 'l',
        '/Ñ|Ń|Ņ|Ň/' => 'N',
        '/ñ|ń|ņ|ň|ŉ/' => 'n',
        '/Ò|Ó|Ô|Õ|Ō|Ŏ|Ǒ|Ő|Ơ|Ø|Ǿ/' => 'O',
        '/ò|ó|ô|õ|ō|ŏ|ǒ|ő|ơ|ø|ǿ|º/' => 'o',
        '/Ŕ|Ŗ|Ř/' => 'R',
        '/ŕ|ŗ|ř/' => 'r',
        '/Ś|Ŝ|Ş|Ș|Š/' => 'S',
        '/ś|ŝ|ş|ș|š|ſ/' => 's',
        '/Ţ|Ț|Ť|Ŧ/' => 'T',
        '/ţ|ț|ť|ŧ/' => 't',
        '/Ù|Ú|Û|Ũ|Ū|Ŭ|Ů|Ű|Ų|Ư|Ǔ|Ǖ|Ǘ|Ǚ|Ǜ/' => 'U',
        '/ù|ú|û|ũ|ū|ŭ|ů|ű|ų|ư|ǔ|ǖ|ǘ|ǚ|ǜ/' => 'u',
        '/Ý|Ÿ|Ŷ/' => 'Y',
        '/ý|ÿ|ŷ/' => 'y',
        '/Ŵ/' => 'W',
        '/ŵ/' => 'w',
        '/Ź|Ż|Ž/' => 'Z',
        '/ź|ż|ž/' => 'z',
        '/Æ|Ǽ/' => 'AE',
        '/ß/' => 'ss',
        '/Ĳ/' => 'IJ',
        '/ĳ/' => 'ij',
        '/Œ/' => 'OE',
        '/ƒ/' => 'f'
    );
    $quotedReplacement = preg_quote($separator, '/');
    $merge = array(
        '/[^\s\p{Zs}\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lo}\p{Lt}\p{Lu}\p{Nd}]/mu' => ' ',
        '/[\s\p{Zs}]+/mu' => $separator,
        sprintf('/^[%s]+|[%s]+$/', $quotedReplacement, $quotedReplacement) => '',
    );
    $map = $_transliteration + $merge;
    unset($_transliteration);
    return preg_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $string);
}
```

the error i have is

```
LogicException : Your configuration files are not serializable.
```

what's the solution?

Comment: What's your php version? I think this will be fixed on 7.4

Comment: I suggest you make this method in a separate helper class and refer to it in your configuration as e.g. `'method' => [ HelperClass::class, 'method' ]` since you can't serialise functions (not sure why this needs to be serialised though, are you passing the config object anywhere that then gets queued?)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57029745/6212294) help you?

Comment: @sta php": "^7.3|^8.0

Comment: @apokryfos how use this method in helper class?

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI no:)

Comment: Move this exact method definition in a helper class and then change your configuration to refer to the method in that class the way I mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: @apokryfos send a sample HelperClass  if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't serialise methods it is recommended you don't define methods within your configuration files. This is because if you want to later pass configurations to your queued jobs, this will not work.

You can make a helper class under e.g. your `app` directory:

```
class HelperClass
{
    public static function sluggableCustomSlugMethod($string, $separator = '-')
    {
        $_transliteration = array(
            '/ä|æ|ǽ/' => 'ae',
            '/ö|œ/' => 'oe',
            '/ü/' => 'ue',
            '/Ä/' => 'Ae',
            '/Ü/' => 'Ue',
            '/Ö/' => 'Oe',
            '/À|Á|Â|Ã|Å|Ǻ|Ā|Ă|Ą|Ǎ/' => 'A',
            '/à|á|â|ã|å|ǻ|ā|ă|ą|ǎ|ª/' => 'a',
            '/Ç|Ć|Ĉ|Ċ|Č/' => 'C',
            '/ç|ć|ĉ|ċ|č/' => 'c',
            '/Ð|Ď|Đ/' => 'D',
            '/ð|ď|đ/' => 'd',
            '/È|É|Ê|Ë|Ē|Ĕ|Ė|Ę|Ě/' => 'E',
            '/è|é|ê|ë|ē|ĕ|ė|ę|ě/' => 'e',
            '/Ĝ|Ğ|Ġ|Ģ/' => 'G',
            '/ĝ|ğ|ġ|ģ/' => 'g',
            '/Ĥ|Ħ/' => 'H',
            '/ĥ|ħ/' => 'h',
            '/Ì|Í|Î|Ï|Ĩ|Ī|Ĭ|Ǐ|Į|İ/' => 'I',
            '/ì|í|î|ï|ĩ|ī|ĭ|ǐ|į|ı/' => 'i',
            '/Ĵ/' => 'J',
            '/ĵ/' => 'j',
            '/Ķ/' => 'K',
            '/ķ/' => 'k',
            '/Ĺ|Ļ|Ľ|Ŀ|Ł/' => 'L',
            '/ĺ|ļ|ľ|ŀ|ł/' => 'l',
            '/Ñ|Ń|Ņ|Ň/' => 'N',
            '/ñ|ń|ņ|ň|ŉ/' => 'n',
            '/Ò|Ó|Ô|Õ|Ō|Ŏ|Ǒ|Ő|Ơ|Ø|Ǿ/' => 'O',
            '/ò|ó|ô|õ|ō|ŏ|ǒ|ő|ơ|ø|ǿ|º/' => 'o',
            '/Ŕ|Ŗ|Ř/' => 'R',
            '/ŕ|ŗ|ř/' => 'r',
            '/Ś|Ŝ|Ş|Ș|Š/' => 'S',
            '/ś|ŝ|ş|ș|š|ſ/' => 's',
            '/Ţ|Ț|Ť|Ŧ/' => 'T',
            '/ţ|ț|ť|ŧ/' => 't',
            '/Ù|Ú|Û|Ũ|Ū|Ŭ|Ů|Ű|Ų|Ư|Ǔ|Ǖ|Ǘ|Ǚ|Ǜ/' => 'U',
            '/ù|ú|û|ũ|ū|ŭ|ů|ű|ų|ư|ǔ|ǖ|ǘ|ǚ|ǜ/' => 'u',
            '/Ý|Ÿ|Ŷ/' => 'Y',
            '/ý|ÿ|ŷ/' => 'y',
            '/Ŵ/' => 'W',
            '/ŵ/' => 'w',
            '/Ź|Ż|Ž/' => 'Z',
            '/ź|ż|ž/' => 'z',
            '/Æ|Ǽ/' => 'AE',
            '/ß/' => 'ss',
            '/Ĳ/' => 'IJ',
            '/ĳ/' => 'ij',
            '/Œ/' => 'OE',
            '/ƒ/' => 'f'
        );
        $quotedReplacement = preg_quote($separator, '/');
        $merge = array(
            '/[^\s\p{Zs}\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lo}\p{Lt}\p{Lu}\p{Nd}]/mu' => ' ',
            '/[\s\p{Zs}]+/mu' => $separator,
            sprintf('/^[%s]+|[%s]+$/', $quotedReplacement, $quotedReplacement) => '',
        );
        $map = $_transliteration + $merge;
        unset($_transliteration);
        return preg_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $string);
    }
}
```

Then add this in your config/sluggable:

```
'method' => [ App\HelperClass::class, 'sluggableCustomSlugMethod' ]
```

This should allow you to serialise the configuration when you need to.