# Error on running php artisan config:cache

Tags: laravel-6, php-7.2

when I run the command:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

on console the following errors get shown:

I have deleted my config.php file from boostrap/cache/ but the problem exist.
And also tried the

```
composer dump-autoload -o

php artisan optimize
```

but the problem not getting solved. Also update my composer.

```
 LogicException  : Your configuration files are not serializable.

   at C:\laragon\www\OHNO-News-and-Magazine-CMS-Laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ConfigCacheCommand.php:71
67|             require $configPath;
68|         } catch (Throwable $e) {
69|             $this->files->delete($configPath);
70| 
71|             throw new LogicException('Your configuration files are not serializable.', 0, 
$e);
72|         }
73| 
74|         $this->info('Configuration cached successfully!');
75|     }
```

Exception trace:

```
 1   BadMethodCallException::("Call to undefined method Modules\Language\Entities\LanguageConfig::__set_state()")
  {project}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php:50

 2   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::throwBadMethodCallException("__set_state")
  {project}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php:36

 Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

What could be the solution to get rid of this issues. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Your configuration files are not serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065513/your-configuration-files-are-not-serializable)

Comment: this solve  the issue of config:cache command, but now facing issue on php artisan optimize