# How to implement Laravel password validation rules as string in arrays?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, config

I want to use the out-of-the-box Laravel password validation rules. This is possible by using the `use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password` [class](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#validating-passwords).

So you can use those rules like so:

```php
\Illuminate\Validation\Rule\Password::min(8)->letters()->numbers()->mixedCase()->uncompromised(3)
```

However, you can't use those rules inside a config file, like in [this package](https://github.com/jeffgreco13/filament-breezy/blob/1.x/config/filament-breezy.php#L26) because you get the following error when running

```
artisan config:cache
```

> ❯ artisan config:cache                                                                                                                                                                   > ─╯
> Configuration cache cleared successfully.
>
> LogicException
>
> Your configuration files are not serializable.
>
> at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ConfigCacheCommand.php:84
> 80▕             require $configPath;
> 81▕         } catch (Throwable $e) {
> 82▕             $this->files->delete($configPath);
> 83▕
> ➜  84▕             throw new LogicException('Your configuration files are not serializable.', 0, $e);
> 85▕         }
> 86▕
> 87▕         $this->info('Configuration cached successfully.');
> 88▕     }
>
> 1   bootstrap/cache/config.php:859
> Error::("Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password::__set_state()")

After reading the docs, it seems that you can't use those password rules as strings inside an array like so:

```
"password_rules" => ['min:8'],
```

So checking the [available rules](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#available-validation-rules), the rest of the following rules (letters, mixedCase, uncompromised) are not available.

Then, is there a workaround to set those password rules inside the config file?
(so that, I can avoid the `LogicException: Your configuration files are not serializable.` after executing the `artisan config:cache` command).

Comment: Laravel describes how to [set the default password rules](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#defining-default-password-rules) in one of the Application Service Providers.

Comment: @aynber Thanks, I tried it. But the problem persists, since in the config file, I have to call the class like so `'password' => ['required', Password::defaults()],`.  Calling the class inside a config file causes the `LogicException: Your configuration files are not serializable` on `artisan config:cache`  ... Then, the question. How do I workaround it?

Comment: Why do you need it inside of a config file?

Comment: Because I am using the Filament-Breezy package. It has that [config file](https://github.com/jeffgreco13/filament-breezy/blob/1.x/config/filament-breezy.php#L26) where you can set the password rules.

Comment: For right now, [you won't be able to use the Password class in the config class](https://github.com/jeffgreco13/filament-breezy/issues/29). You'll need to set it manually

Comment: @aynber How would I implement it manually? Any ideas or examples?

Comment: Look at the [validation rules] to see what's available. `alphanumeric` would cover the mixed case / letters / numbers, though I would leave that off to allow all characters. I don't know if there's an uncompromised in there, though

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password;

$rules = [
    'password' => [
        'required',
        'string',
        Password::min(8)
            ->mixedCase()
            ->numbers()
            ->symbols()
            ->uncompromised(),
        'confirmed'
    ],
]
```

Try using the above code it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it validates well. But the thing is that I still get the `LogicException. Your configuration files are not serializable.` error when I execute the `artisan config:cache` command.

Comment: have you installed any package ? if yes try to remove it and to do config:cahce again

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Laravel person, but you can put the config into an array and then unpack it later in your app with something like this:

```php
// for illustration
class Mock {
    public function __call($name, $args) {
        printf("called: %s(%s)\n", $name, implode(', ', $args));
        return $this;
    }
    
    // this is awful. never do this.
    // in Laravel the min() function, and only this function, is basically
    // an alias to the constructor, which is weird.
    public static function __callStatic($name, $args) {
        return (new self())->$name(...$args);
    }
}

$params = [
    'min' => [8],
    'letters' => [],
    'numbers' => [],
    'mixedCase' => [],
    'uncompromised' => [3]
];

$o = NULL;
foreach( $params as $func => $args ) {
    if( is_null($o) ) {
        $o = Mock::$func(...$args);
    } else {
        $o = $o->$func(...$args);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
called: min(8)
called: letters()
called: numbers()
called: mixedCase()
called: uncompromised(3)
```